# CAN Bus checksum

Tags: crc

Maybe someone can help me with algorithm for checksum calculation. CRC 8 does not fit. Left byte is CRC.

```
B9 30 13 00 00 20 00 00
36 31 13 00 00 20 00 00
BA 32 13 00 00 20 00 00
35 33 13 00 00 20 00 00
BF 34 13 00 00 20 00 00
30 35 13 00 00 20 00 00
BC 36 13 00 00 20 00 00
33 37 13 00 00 20 00 00
B5 38 13 00 00 20 00 00
3A 39 13 00 00 20 00 00
B6 3A 13 00 00 20 00 00
39 3B 13 00 00 20 00 00
B3 3C 13 00 00 20 00 00
3C 3D 13 00 00 20 00 00
B0 3E 13 00 00 20 00 00
3F 3F 13 00 00 20 00 00

7E 01 00 00 00 20 00 00
F2 02 00 00 00 20 00 00
7D 03 00 00 00 20 00 00
F7 04 00 00 00 20 00 00
78 05 00 00 00 20 00 00
F4 06 00 00 00 20 00 00
7B 07 00 00 00 20 00 00
FD 08 00 00 00 20 00 00
72 09 00 00 00 20 00 00
FE 0A 00 00 00 20 00 00
71 0B 00 00 00 20 00 00
FB 0C 00 00 00 20 00 00
74 0D 00 00 00 20 00 00
F8 0E 00 00 00 20 00 00
77 0F 00 00 00 20 00 00
F1 00 00 00 00 20 00 00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find anything using the whole message; however, because the last 5 bytes are the same in all the messages you provided, I omitted them one by one and ran reveng on the truncated messages.

reveng provides the following output if we leave out the last 4 bytes:

```
./reveng -w 8 -s 301300B9 31130036 321300BA 33130035
width=8  poly=0x1d  init=0xff  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0xff  check=0x4b  residue=0xc4  name="CRC-8/SAE-J1850"
```

This algorithm works for all of the samples you provided.